# How to pass id dynamically to a popup using php

Tags: javascript, php, popupwindow

How to pass id dynamically to a popup using php? I need to auto increment id value to popup window.Plz help me to solve this issue.

```
include("config.php");

$query=mysql_query("select * from reports_form");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
 $id=$row['id'];
  $job_detail1 = $row['job_description']; ?>   
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  }</script> 

       <td align="center"> <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
       <a href="#myPopup<?php echo $id; ?>"> Click me!</a>

  <span class="popuptext"  id="myPopup"><?php echo "$job_detail1";?>            </span>
  </div></td>

    </tr>

  <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are getting valid Id from PHP?

Comment: i need to getting the value according to the corresponding id. I getting only one value.

Answer (score 1):

Hi first you shouldn't use your script in loop, and pass variable your function  It should be below

```
?>
<script>
 function myFunction(id) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
console.log(id)
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  }
</script> 
<?php
include("config.php");   
$query=mysql_query("select * from reports_form");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
 $id=$row['id'];
  $job_detail1 = $row['job_description']; ?> 

       <td align="center"> <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $id;?>)">
       <a href="#myPopup<?php echo $id; ?>"> Click me!</a>

  <span class="popuptext"  id="myPopup"><?php echo "$job_detail1";?>    </span>
  </div></td>

</tr>

  <?php
 }
 ?>
```

**Second working code**

```
<?php
//your prev code here
?>
<script>
    function myFunction(id) {
        var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        console.log(id)
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
</script>
    <table>
<?php

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
{
$id=$i;
$job_detail1 = 'desc'.$i; ?>

<td align="center"> <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $id;?>)">
        <a href="#myPopup<?php echo $id; ?>"> Click me!</a>

        <span class="popuptext"  id="myPopup"><?php echo "$job_detail1";?>    </span>
    </div></td>

</tr>

<?php
}

?>
    </table>
```

Screenshot[image]

Comment: Ok, I think there is a misunderstanding on my side, first where is the syntax error js or php also what is your purpose that using  "id" in this code<a href="#myPopup<?php echo $id; ?>"> Click me!</a> so this code

Comment: @FerhatBAŞ,Thanks for your support,. first one is better than second one. I'm expecting the output is id from db according to the onclick , then listing the details of that id.

Comment: Second coe just proof for working code because i dont have your db just change for loop instead of your while